# Использование $.proxy внутри $('body').on('focus')

Tags: jquery

Как правильно использовать функцию `$.proxy()`? Именно нужно с `$.proxy()` реализовать вывод в консоль, `"Hello world"` внутри функции `$('body').on('focus')`. Я делаю так, но у меня ничего не работает:

```
<input type="text" data-name="1" />
<input type="text" data-name="2" />
<input type="text" data-name="3" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').each(function()
    {
        $('body').on('focus', 'input', $.proxy(console.log('Hello world!')));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.proxy принимает на вход два аргумента - функцию и контекст. А вы ей даете только результат выполнения `console.log`, т.е. `undefined`. Вам нужно обернуть это дело в функцию:

```
$('body').on('focus', 'input', $.proxy(function(){
    console.log('Hello world!');
}));
```

А еще ваша конструкция с `$('input').each` лишняя, т.к. `$('body').on('focus','input'` и так покрывает все инпуты на странице. А вы вешаете на каждый инпут столько обработчиков, сколько у вас инпутов.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло!